# Can't resolve docker related sbt tags

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt, sbt-docker

I'm trying to add sbt-docker to my sbt build of my play website but I'm running into an issue.  For some reason none of the docker related stuff on the bottom can resolve.

project/plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.9")
```

build.sbt

```
name := "personal_site"

version := "1.1"

lazy val `personal_site` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala,DockerPlugin)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws , specs2 % Test )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

dockerfile in docker := {
    val targetDir = "/usr/src"

    new Dockerfile {
        from("flurdy/activator")
        //More goes here
    }
}

imageNames in docker := Seq(
    // Sets the latest tag
    ImageName(s"${name.value}:latest"),

    // Sets a name with a tag that contains the project version
    ImageName(
        namespace = None,
        repository = name.value,
        tag = Some("v" + version.value)
    )
)
```

Here's an image of what it looks like in IntelliJ

[image]

I've also tried adding `addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker" % "1.4.0")` to my `project/plugins.sbt` but I get this error about `DockerPlugin` being imported twice.

```
~/Sync/Projects/Programming/Personal_Site (master ✘)✹ ᐅ  sbt clean
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ryan/Sync/Projects/Programming/Personal_Site/project
/home/ryan/Sync/Projects/Programming/Personal_Site/build.sbt:5: error: reference to DockerPlugin is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import _root_.sbtdocker.DockerPlugin
and import _root_.com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin
lazy val `personal_site` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala,DockerPlugin)
```

Comment: Will `sbt compile` work when you remove the imports? In other words, are you sure it's a problem with your code and not IntelliJ?

Comment: What imports do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the error message. Please paste the contents of your plugins.sbt, it looks like you may be importing two different plugins for creating docker images, causing the ambiguity

Comment: I did, it's at the top

Comment: When I get the error it's because I tried to add this `addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker" % "1.4.0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `build.sbt` config to this.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(sbtdocker.DockerPlugin, PlayScala)
```

It removes the ambiguity by using the full name to DockerPlugin, since `sbt-native-packager` uses the same name for its Docker plugin I believe.

Maybe worth raising a Github issue with the author's repo so they can document it in the project docs.

Comment: Oh interesting, does the `PlayScala` plugin include the `sbt-native-packager`?  I assume it must since I'm not actually including it manually,

Comment: Yep, it is included automatically so you can package your app up with commands like `activator dist`